# Spark KMeans clustering: get the number of sample assigned to a cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark Mlib for kmeans clustering. I have a set of vectors from which I want to determine the most likely cluster center. So I will run kmeans clustering training on this set and select the cluster with the highest number of vector assigned to it.

Therefore I need to know the number of vectors assigned to each cluster after training (i.e KMeans.run(...)). But I can not find a way to retrieve this information from KMeanModel result. I probably need to run `predict` on all training vectors and count the label which appear the most.

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Hierarchical Clustering or K-means?

Comment: Hi, it is kmeans. I have updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: When you say "the most likely cluster's center" do you mean the centroid?

Comment: Yup. `KMeans.run(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)`. Let say i have numClusters = 3. I want to select one cluster with the majority of vector assigned to it out of 3 result clusters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this info is not provided by the model, and you have to run `predict`. Here is an example of doing so in a parallelized way (Spark v. 1.5.1):

```python
 from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
 from numpy import array
 data = array([0.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 9.0,8.0, 8.0,9.0, 10.0, 9.0]).reshape(5, 2)
 data
 # array([[  0.,   0.],
 #       [  1.,   1.],
 #       [  9.,   8.],
 #       [  8.,   9.],
 #       [ 10.,   9.]])

 k = 2 # no. of clusters
 model = KMeans.train(
                sc.parallelize(data), k, maxIterations=10, runs=30, initializationMode="random",
                seed=50, initializationSteps=5, epsilon=1e-4)

 cluster_ind = model.predict(sc.parallelize(data))
 cluster_ind.collect()
 # [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

`cluster_ind` is an RDD of the same cardinality with our initial data, and it shows which cluster each datapoint belongs to. So, here we have two clusters, one with 3 datapoints (cluster 0) and one with 2 datapoints (cluster 1). Notice that we have run the prediction method in a parallel fashion (i.e. on an RDD) - `collect()` is used here only for our demonstration purposes, and it is not needed in a 'real' situation.

Now, we can get the cluster sizes with

```python
 cluster_sizes = cluster_ind.countByValue().items()
 cluster_sizes
 # [(0, 3), (1, 2)]
```

From this, we can get the maximum cluster index & size as

```python
 from operator import itemgetter
 max(cluster_sizes, key=itemgetter(1))
 # (0, 3)
```

i.e. our biggest cluster is cluster 0, with a size of 3 datapoints, which can be easily verified by inspection of `cluster_ind.collect()` above.

Comment: Thanks. I go with it. But it seems inefficient as they are duplication of work.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'inefficient" and 'duplication of work': if you look at the [source code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/clustering.html#KMeansModel), you'll see that cluster indices are not **included** in the model (i.e. it is not that they are included but not accessible). I guess this has to do with the purpose of Spark in dealing with big datasets, although I agree that, for people coming from a 'non-big data' context, it is counter-intuitive (as is the term 'predict' itself for clustering)...